# How to display percentage of CPU load info set by stress-ng utility at specific interval into terminal?

Tags: cpu, stress-testing

I need to write stress testing utility to set all CPU to specific load value and need to display CPU load to terminal window at every 1 sec(which depends on user pass argument) so user can verified CPU load

I am setting CPU load to 80% (based on user input)and running stress-ng utility for specific time(120 sec) into background

```
stress-ng -c 8 -l 80 --timeout 120s &
```

Now How can I display all CPU load(here I am doing stress testing for 8 core) info into terminal every 1 second so user can verified that whatever load value he set using utility all CPU currently running at the same load

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your processor make and model, you might be able to use turbostat (linux-tools-common package) to get what you want. It works with most recent Intel processors and, if your version of turbostat is new enough, many AMD processors.

Example, where I have a 12 instances of a program running at 80% utilization at a work/sleep frequency of 273 hertz on a 6 core 12 CPU Intel 10600K processor, and I am sampling at 6 seconds per sample:

```
$ sudo turbostat --quiet --show Core,CPU,Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp --interval 6
Core    CPU     Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt
-       -       78.55   4800    90958   67      85.25
0       0       78.53   4800    7598    67      85.25
0       6       78.55   4800    7579
1       1       78.55   4800    7570
1       7       78.56   4800    7568
2       2       78.55   4800    7594
2       8       78.56   4800    7575
3       3       78.54   4800    7570
3       9       78.56   4800    7574
4       4       78.55   4800    7569
4       10      78.57   4800    7564
5       5       78.54   4800    7563
5       11      78.55   4800    7634
Core    CPU     Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt
-       -       78.54   4800    90801   67      85.27
0       0       78.55   4800    7567    67      85.27
0       6       78.54   4800    7575
1       1       78.55   4800    7562
1       7       78.55   4800    7576
2       2       78.54   4800    7563
2       8       78.54   4800    7569
3       3       78.54   4800    7563
3       9       78.54   4800    7563
4       4       78.54   4800    7564
4       10      78.55   4800    7571
5       5       78.55   4800    7562
5       11      78.54   4800    7566
Core    CPU     Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt
-       -       78.53   4800    90805   68      85.00
0       0       78.51   4800    7567    68      85.00
0       6       78.56   4800    7574
1       1       78.57   4800    7565
1       7       78.43   4800    7571
2       2       78.45   4800    7565
2       8       78.58   4800    7570
3       3       78.55   4800    7564
3       9       78.53   4800    7566
4       4       78.54   4800    7564
4       10      78.54   4800    7570
5       5       78.54   4800    7561
5       11      78.55   4800    7568
Core    CPU     Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt
-       -       78.50   4800    90765   68      84.39
0       0       78.34   4800    7569    68      84.39
0       6       78.58   4800    7573
1       1       78.59   4800    7560
1       7       78.36   4800    7570
2       2       78.52   4800    7563
2       8       78.55   4800    7567
3       3       78.30   4800    7535
3       9       78.58   4800    7566
4       4       78.54   4800    7561
4       10      78.55   4800    7569
5       5       78.55   4800    7564
5       11      78.54   4800    7568
```